# How to prove that this map makes sense?

Tags: tensor-products

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $r$-modules . Let $L$ be a module homomorphism from $A$ to $B$. Now consider the map $f$ from $A \otimes A$ to  $B \otimes B$, which takes a pure tensor $a \otimes b$ to $L(a) \otimes L(b)$. How do I prove this map makes sense? Let $x \in A\otimes A$ and $x=\Sigma c a\otimes b= \Sigma c^{'} a^{'}\otimes b^{'}$. How to show that $f(\Sigma c a\otimes b)= f( \Sigma c^{'} a^{'}\otimes b^{'})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the univeral property. Consider an bilinear map $A\times A\rightarrow B\otimes B$ with $f(a,a')=L(a)\otimes L(a')$. For any $(a,a')\in A\times A$ this is well defined. Then try to show it factors through $A\otimes A$ and coincide with the map you desired.